# Trying to retrieve a value from array, but getting undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having some trouble trying to retrieve a value from an array in Angular/TS. The main idea is simple: I have an endpoint that returns a list of objects already registred, so I need do check if the itens in the screen are already registred and inform the user.
The data is returned from the endpoint normally, and I can console.log the result of that array, witch is something like that:

```
0: (1) [...]
    0: Object { nome: "teste", ip: "x.x.x.x", port: "x"},
    length: 1
```

The problem is: I can console.log the entire array, but when I try to access an item of that same array by key, or to use the find or foreach functions, I keep getting that the result is `undefined`.

```
console.log(arr) // returns the entire array
console.log(arr[0]) // returns undefined
```

Comment: Run `Array.isArray(arr)` to make sure it is in fact an array. Also, try logging `Object.keys(arr)` to see if a key "0" exists.

Comment: ```Array.isArray(arr)``` returns true; ```Object.keys(arr)``` returns an empty array; and ```arr.keys()``` returns an empty array iterator.

Comment: So, me thinks something is added the data to your array after you console.log it. Console.log will show you an up-to-date value of an object. So that could be why you can see it in the console, but not when you access it directly. Can you share a snippet of your API retrieval and console.log?

Comment: I've thought on that too, but it is strange, because if I make my code this way: ```console.log(arr); // Return my array```; ```console.log(arr[0]); // Return undefined```; ```console.log(Object.keys(arr)); // Returns an empty array```; ```console.log(arr); // Still returns my array```. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if that was the case, the last console.log should result in an empty array, right?

Comment: That is incorrect. You can do a simple test in the browser console to demonstrate what I mean. Create a new array `let a = []`. Then log the keys `Object.keys(a)`. Then log that array `a`. Then add an element `a.push('abc')`. If you open the logged `a`, it'll show `abc`, but the logged keys won't be updated.

Comment: You are right. So much that, if I put an alert(arr[0]), the data is normally loaded by the page. I'm trying to solve it by using an asynchronous function. But still, it doesn't work properly. Any other idea on that matter?

Comment: Post your code that loads the data